# Wrire script in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to write `<scrip></script>` for API address form but I don't know where to write .
I created file a script.php in resources/views/script.php then I call 
`<script src= "{{ asset('resources/views/script.php') }}" >`in app.blade.php but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `script.php` name to `script.blade.php` then you can import it using `@include('script');`

Comment: @include('script'); Where do write?

Comment: in which file you want to run the script ?

Comment: check this : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews

Answer (score 0):

Change `resources/views/script.php` to `resources/views/script.blade.php`

Then you can use the blade template engine :

```
@include('script');
```

Comment: Can i write script in form page?

Comment: it can not to found script.blade.php

Comment: `@include('script');` call your `script.blade.php` file, so write your js code on `resources/views/script.blade.php`